# Data frame "*" only defined for equally-sized data frames

Tags: r

I am trying to do the following calculation on the following data

```
  Class Returns_Jan_18 Returns_Feb_18 Assets_Jan_18 Assets_Feb_18
    zxc1       3           NaN            150           153 
    zc2        5           NaN            30            60
    2343       NaN         -7             8             NA  
    4zcz       NaN          2             NA            80            
    zxcEd      2            1             2             60           

 asset_column <-grep("^Assets_", names(df1))
 return_column <-grep("^Returns_", names(df1))
 colSums(df1[asset_column], na.rm = TRUE) 
 df1[asset_column]/colSums(df1[asset_column], na.rm = TRUE)
```

The above code works fine. However, as soon as I try the following

```
 (df1[asset_column]/colSums(df1[asset_column], na.rm = TRUE) * df1[return_column])
```

I receive the following error
‘*’ only defined for equally-sized data frames

I'm not sure why - I think it might have something to do with the NaN as the following is shown in the global environment window? But I'm not really sure.

```
 return_column integer(empty)
```

Comment: Reason is that `colSums` returns a vector while `df1[return_column]` is a data.frame with n number of rows.  You may need to make the dimensions correct by replicating the colSums output

Comment: @akrun thanks - still not sure, I have added an example of my data. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not able to reproduce the error though.  It s working fine for me  `(df1[asset_column]/colSums(df1[asset_column], na.rm = TRUE) * df1[return_column])
  Assets_Jan_18 Assets_Feb_18
1    2.36842105           NaN
2    0.42492918           NaN ...`